# Trigger Jenkins Pipeline job on merge event for gitlab MR

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

this should be fairly basic, but when I research I come to things like gerrit triggrs and whatnot, which seem way too complicated for doing something simple like this.

I would like to do something like either this in the JobDSL script:

```
pipelineJob('deploy-game') {
    definition {
        environmentVariables {
          env('ENVIRONMENT', "${ENVIRONMENT}")

          keepBuildVariables(true)
        }
        cpsScm {
            scm {
                git{
                    remote {
                        url('https://blabla.git')
                        credentials('gitlab-credentials')
                    }
                    branches('${gitlabsourcebranch}')
                }
            }
            scriptPath('path/to/this.jenkinsfile')
        }
        triggers {
            gitlabPush {
                buildOnMergeRequestEvents(true)
                if ($gitlabMergeRequestState == 'merged')  // this part
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, trigger on all MR events, and then filter out in the pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  environment {
    ENVIRONMENT   = "${ENVIRONMENT}"
  }
  triggers {
    $gitlabMergeRequestState == 'merged' // this one
  }
  stages {
        stage ('do-stuff') {
          agent {
            label 'agent'
          }
          steps {
            sh 'some commands ...'
          }
        }
   }
}
```

How do I do this ?

Comment: AFAIK no plugin does this. We set up a webhook from Github that is sent on merge events and triggers a special job receiving webhook payload, parsing it, and triggering the actual job with branch name etc.

Comment: Okay that is disappointing, but I guess it explains why I could not find something .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is how it should be, I hope this is what you are looking for it.

```
pipelineJob('Job_Name') {
          definition {
            cpsScm {
                lightweight(true)
                triggers {
                    gitlabPush {
                        buildOnMergeRequestEvents(true) // it will trigger build when MR is opened.
                        buildOnPushEvents(true)
                        commentTrigger('retry a build') // When you write the comment on MR on gitlab. it will also trigger build
                        enableCiSkip(true)
                        rebuildOpenMergeRequest('source')
                        skipWorkInProgressMergeRequest(false)
                        targetBranchRegex('.*master.*|.*release.*') //This mean only push happened to master or release then only trigger jenkins build. Do not trigger build on normal feature branch push until the MR is opened.                   
                    }
                }
                configure {
                    it / triggers / 'com.dabsquared.gitlabjenkins.GitLabPushTrigger' << secretToken('ADD_TOKEN_FROM_JENKINS_JOB')
                }
                scm {      
                    git {
                        remote {
                            credentials('ID')
                            url("git@URL.git")
                            branch("refs/heads/master")
                        }
                    }
                }
                scriptPath("jenkinsfile")
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: So what I want is to NOT trigger on opening/updating MR, only merging. Also: what is the configure {} part ? Maybe if you could explain a bit more, would appreciate it!

Comment: ok if you want to  NOT trigger on opening/updating MR, only merging then you should set the ```buildOnMergeRequestEvents(false)``` and this ```targetBranchRegex('.*master.*|.*release.*')``` only trigger build when barnch get's merged to master or release branch

Comment: And about configure {}. There is no other way to configure the job with webhook configuration so you use to enable it from jenkins core package.

Comment: Right so by default it is onPush. Ok I will play with it thanks!

Comment: @Chai if this solve your problem feel free to accept the answer and upvote. Thnaks

Comment: @Chai did it worked ?

Comment: Hi, I only got back to it now. Was away in between. Anyway: Yes I did get it to work. The `targetBranchRegex` together with `buildOnPushEvents(true)` was all it took! I left the Configure {} unused, it was not necessary for me. Thx

Answer (score 0):

To trigger your build when a merge request is opened or when a push is made to an branch that has an open merge request, add the following to your Jenkinsfile

```
triggers
{
    gitlab(triggerOnMergeRequest: true, triggerOpenMergeRequestOnPush: "source", branchFilterType: 'All')
    cron(cron_string)
}
```

See https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#defined-variables for more "trigger" options

To only execute stages if it was triggered from a merge request, you can check if the `gitlabMergeRequestId` is set. If you do this in a when block, like the following, it will only execute your stages if the ID is set, which means it came from a merge request. This when block will only execute the stages if it is the master or develop branch, or it was triggered by a merge request

```
stage("Build")
{
    when
    {
        anyOf
        {
            branch 'master'
            branch 'develop'
            changeRequest() // Jenkins documentation claims this will check if a
                            // GitLab Merge Request triggered the build, but it
                            // was not working for me. It could be the version of
                            // Jenkins I am using. I have seen this work with
                            // Bitbucket. Anyone know?
            expression{gitlabMergeRequestId != null} // Is a merge request
        }
    }
    stages // Will no execute if no develop, master or a merge request
    {
        stage('MyStage')
        {
            :
            :
        }
    }
}
```